# UWP MapControl: distinction between user- and app-manipulation

Tags: windows, uwp, bing-maps, uwp-maps

Within an UWP-App containing a MapControl, is there a way to distinct between a manipulation to the map made by the user (e.g. by pinch to zoom) and one, that is made by the app itself? (e.g. by calling `mapControl.TrySetViewAsync(...)`)

It doesn't seem like that there's an eventhandler for that, right?
I already tried several ones (like `LoadingStatusChanged` or `CenterChanged`), but none of them are making any difference between user- and app-manipulation..

Comment: Just found this suggestion brought to the bing-devs: https://binglistens.uservoice.com/forums/283355-ideas/suggestions/9494889-add-a-centermanuallychanged-event-to-mapcontrol - but is there a way to do it yourself atm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to register to receive a [TargetCameraChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapcontrol.targetcamerachanged.aspx) event that will fire whenever the map view changes. The [MapTargetCameraChangedEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.maptargetcamerachangedeventargs.aspx) returned contain a [ChangeReason](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.maptargetcamerachangedeventargs.changereason.aspx) property.

The ChangeReason property will be *System*, *UserInteraction* or *Programmatic*.

Map movements caused by calling APIs such as `TrySetViewAsync(...)` cause events that have `ChangeReason == Programmatic`, and movements caused by user actions such as pinch to zoom should have `ChangeReason == UserInteraction`.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: I've made a small edit to your answer to make it more readable (at least as I see it), if you find it bad, don't hesitate to rollback. Also +1 for the answer.